# Insert charcters in a long string python

Tags: python, json

I have one bad-formatted python dictionary:

```
poke = "{
    bulbasaur: {
        num: 1,
        name: "Bulbasaur",
        types: ["Grass", "Poison"],
        genderRatio: {M: 0.875, F: 0.125},
        baseStats: {hp: 45, atk: 49, deff: 49, spa: 65, spd: 65, spe: 45},
        abilities: {0: "Overgrow", H: "Chlorophyll"},
        heightm: 0.7,
        weightkg: 6.9,
        color: "Green",
        evos: ["ivysaur"],
        eggGroups: ["Monster", "Grass"],
    },
```

(as you can imagine there's a list of all pokemon)

so I want to add `"` just before `:`, and in the beggining of that word, so I can have a Python dictionary.

How can I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Are the keys guaranteed to be the first word on each line? Use a regular expression.

Comment: You really should fix the problem at the source so it produces correct JSON. Unless you have guarantees about the layout and characters used in keys, trying to fix it up will not be safe.

Comment: It's not "poorly-formatted" python `dict`, it's just a different data representation, the string you describe is a valid `YAML` or `jsonnet`

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 2):

This string looks like a valid `jsonnet` or `YAML`

Just use the right module to parse:

```
import json
import _jsonnet

json_str = _jsonnet.evaluate_snippet(
    "poke", poke)

json_obj = json.loads(json_str)
```

Example taken from [here](https://jsonnet.org/ref/bindings.html)

Answer (score 0):

Is the string formatted the way you posted with newline characters separating lines? If this is the case here's the solution to your problem, I will write in pseudo since it is pretty straightforward to translate it in Python, they are almost the same.

```
- Loop over each poke
- Split over \n to get the pairs k,v
- For each k,v split on the ':' character, map each element e to " + e + " and finally join them on ':'.
```